# How to view a telegram account by chat id?

Tags: telegram

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to view or message a non-contact person who has no username, with his/her chat id?
I only got a chat id.

Comment: For Bot or user account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sendMessage` method and pass chat_id as chat_id you have it and then send message to that user.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR_API_TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat id you have>&text=Hello world
```

Comment: Sorry but that method does not work. It works if i only put my own chat id not others.

Comment: bot can't start chat and user should start chat before, then telegram bots can send message

Answer (score 0):

If your bot have received messages from that user, you can use [inline mention](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendMessage-cf42d4b9), and your user account can view his profile/PM him.

But unfortunately, bot account can't initiate chat for now :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what programming language you use but I think you can use some Telegram client library like [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)

> Telethon is Telegram client implementation in Python 3 which uses the latest available API of Telegram

If you use PHP, use [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto)  instead.

Comment: Thank you very much but, since I'm not a programmer could you explain how i use two things you mentioned above?. By the way, i guess there should be something ( a URL maybe) to send messges directly to any user you want to.

Comment: I do not think there is a way, except that you use these clients and you also have programming.